# Intergrate WP into website

Tags: get-posts

I am trying to integrate WordPress into my website. I can pull all the information, except the image.

I use the code below:

```
require( 'my-blog/wp-blog-header.php' );

$posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=1&order=ASC&orderby=post_title' );
foreach ( $posts as $post ) : 
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_date(); 
    echo "<br />";
    the_title();   
    the_excerpt();
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will not do anything. In order to integrate Wordpress into an existing website, the best way would probably be to actually install wordpress on the site! This code just pulls up the header.